# error: You have an error in your SQL syntax when creating table in mysql

Tags: sql, syntax, syntax-error

I know what a syntax error is but cannot find any error when creating this table:
my code

```
CREATE TABLE branch supplier (
     branch_id INT,
     supplier_name VARCHAR(40),
     supply_type VARCHAR(40),
     PRIMARY KEY (branch_id, supplier_name),
     FOREIGN KEY (branch_id) REFERENCES branch(branch_id) ON DELETE CASCADE
 );
```

and the error I'm getting

> You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'supplier ( branch_id INT, supplier_name VARCHAR(40), supply_type ' at line 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is not allowed to use table names with space(s) unless you use `. This means you need to change this to...

```
CREATE TABLE `branch supplier`...
```

or to something without space, as example

```
CREATE TABLE branch_supplier...
```